# Masking an image view with an image view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, xcode5

I am struggling to figure out how I can mask one image view to another. I am attempting to mask a chat bubble image view to a image view that contains a picture, exactly like iMessage.

I have tried every combination of imageView.layer.mask I can possibly think of and it all fails. The hard part of this is because the bubble image view is made from a stretchable image. I cannot use a regular image mask it doesn't work.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try a hierarchy of views like this instead:

```
> Cell //The table view cell for one message
    > UIView //Subview of your message table view cell - holds image views and/or text
        > UIImageView //Subview of the UIView - the bubble image
            > UIImageView //Also a subview of the UIView - your picture message
            > UITextView //Alternative subview of the UIView - if the message isn't a picture
```

Comment: I wasn't sure how to do that since you can't add subviews to an image view with storyboard.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear about that. I didn't mean to add subviews to the second `UIImageView`, I just meant to overlay them (both being subviews of the `UIView` which acts as the "message" view). I'll edit my answer for clarity.

Comment: I managed to make it work for the most part by using a stretchable mask image with the same frame as the chat bubble and masked the photo with it. It worked pretty good.

Comment: I still need to adjust the cap insets a bit but its like 90% there.